# Redirecting subdomain to another server shows server's IP

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, subdomain

Let's say I have a domain x.com which is hosted on server1.
I made a subdomain sub.x.com and pointed it towards server2.
All of this worked successfully, except now I see server2's IP instead of sub.x.com in the address bar.

So, redirecting sub.x.com to another server obviously worked because I get to the destination I wanted, but how do I get rid of the IP address and show wanted URL?
Server2 is running a simple REST API, and the only thing installed is node.js and some dependencies (no apache or anything else; it didn't work with apache installed neither).

Do I have to install something on server2, change some configs, add SSL, do something else?

I've seen a myriad topics with similar questions, however, non of the answers worked for me. Plus, I'm a beginner in this which may explain a lot.

Comment: DNS doesn't do redirects. If going to `sub.x.com` in your browser takes you to an IP address, figure out why the webserver is issuing a redirect. (It *might* help to give the actual domains here.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks! Maybe I didn't explain things well or, more likely, tags added some confusion to what I wanted to do. I'm perfectly happy with redirecting, that's exactly what I wanted. The problem is the fact that clients will see the IP address instead of URL when visiting the subdomain.

Comment: How did you "point"  sub.x.com to server2?

Comment: There's a cpanel option to create a subdomain and then there is another option to redirect it. This redirection should be implemented with a RewriteRule in .htaccess.